# Why can't I find the value of years in compound interest, when there is a compound frequency?

Tags: logarithms, finance

I'm trying to figure out why when I do not have an 'a' value (Compound Frequency) I can no longer use logarithms to solve for 'n' (number of years). Let the formula look like this:

```
FV=PV(1+(i/100)/a)^na
```

So by using the next formula:

```
(log(FV/PV))/(log(1+(i/100)/a))=n
```

It only appears to work when a is equal to 1. When I change it to something like 52, I end up get the incorrect number. Try using these variables:

- FV = 122.12
- PV = 100
- i = 10
- a = 52

I know that n=2, but using the second formula I constantly get 104. Why is this happening?
Apologies for poor formatting, I'm just in a rush.

Comment: The right hand side should be $na$, not $a$.

Answer (score 1):

If you take logs of $\frac{FV}{PV}=\left(1+\frac{i}{100\cdot a}\right)^{n\cdot a}$ you get

$$\log\left(\frac{FV}{PV} \right)=n\cdot a \cdot \log\left(1+\frac{i}{100\cdot a} \right),$$

which leads to

$$n=\frac{\log\left(\frac{FV}{PV} \right)}{a \cdot \log\left(1+\frac{i}{100\cdot a} \right)}$$

*Numerical example:*

$$n=\frac{\log\left(\frac{122.12}{100} \right)}{52 \cdot \log\left(1+\frac{10}{100\cdot 52} \right)}= 2.00...$$

It is comprehensible?

**Update**

That´s the formula for compound Interest  for monthly (or other period) compounding interest $FV=PV\cdot \left(1+\frac{r}a \right)^{n\cdot a}$. Similar formula can be seen [here](https://www.thecalculatorsite.com/articles/finance/compound-interest-formula.php). Here r is the yearly interest rate in decimal representation, e.g. $r=0.04$ for $r=4\%$. In your case it is $r=\frac{i}{100}$, with $i=4$. So you divide the interest rate $\frac{i}{100}$ by $a$: $$\frac{\frac{i}{100}}{a}.$$ That is a double fraction as $$\frac{\frac{m}{n}}{\frac{s}{t}}$$ In your example we have $m=i, n=100, s=a$ and $t=1$. We divide a fraction by another fraction by **multiplying the first fraction by the reciprocal of the second fraction**.  Thus we get $$\frac{m}{n}\cdot \frac{t}{s}=\frac{i}{100}\cdot \frac{1}{a}=\frac{i}{a\cdot 100}$$

Comment: This makes sense, thank you so much! However, could you explain why you now multiply a instead of divide it by 100?

Comment: @orio73 I´ve made an update.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the way the formula is formatted.

[image]
now plug in the variables